# CSS: how to get scrollbars responsive for div inside container when user resizes it upwards

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying make scrollbars responsive **(my height)** for my `div` inside the `container` when the user resizes it upwards, if you see right now when it happen the scroll disappear and the arrows too.

Can I make these two scrolls get responsive and not disappear when I resize it upwards?

I mean always be seen by the user, to navigate the text using the arrows?

[image]

[image]

The images above show where arrows disappear when the user resizes the browser upwards, so I want for my green div be responsive and the arrows always be displayed.

Edit: the width is fine I am trying fix the height to be responsive when the user resize it from the bottom to up understand?

css:

```
html,
body {
  background-color: palette(dark-white);
  font: $font-weight--normal $font-size-root/#{$line-height-base} $font-family--primary;
  // height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border:1px solid red;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.sidebar-left-test {
    height:500px;
    width:30%;
    border:1px solid green;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

.content{
    height: 500px;
    width:70%;
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="md-col-12">
    header
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="sidebar-left-test">
      md-4
      <br> md-4
      <br> md-4
      <br> md-4
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="content">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q7kjm9pn/

Comment: Your containers are a fixed height and always have scrollbars, not entirely sure what you are asking here.  Please can you clarify

Comment: sorry I did a Edit.
the images above show whe arrows disappear when the user resize the browser upwards, so I want to my green div be responsive and the arrows always be seeing  .

edit: the width is fine I am trying fix the height to be responsive when the user resize it from the bottom to up understand?

Comment: ah, in which case you need to make your container responsive to the browser window. uncomment that height 100% in the body and html. Then make your container-fluid a percentage height of the body, then make sidebar-left-test and its parent 100% height, and same for content and it's parent

Comment: Just seen you have a header - is that a fixed height?

Comment: @Pete i did and look what happen: https://jsfiddle.net/q7kjm9pn/3/ , now the 2 divs does not get  height but if I change for px gets :(, very confusing now.

Comment: how's this: http://www.bootply.com/FakUNmNL3g I've used a bit of display flex and added a container around your body divs

Comment: @Pete OMG you are a genius, can u do the answer and explain I will give the points, thanks a lot man, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comments, here is my answer in [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/FakUNmNL3g).  I have added comments to the snippet below so you can see what the styles are doing

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

html,
body {
  background-color: palette(dark-white);
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid red;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
.sidebar-left-test {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.content {
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

/* new styles */
.container-fluid {
  display: flex;          /* make outer container flex */
  flex-direction: column;  /* make md col 12 divs into 2 rows */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;           /* make the height of the container 100% of the body if less than max height */
  max-height: 600px;      /* max height of the container */
}
.md-col-12 {
  width: 100%;            /* make sure these rows take up 100% width*/
}
#header {
  flex-grow: 0;   /* this is so that the header is as high as it's content */
}
#body {
  flex-grow: 1;   /* this makes the body take up the rest of the height inside the container */
  display: flex;  /* make this flex as well so we can get the two child divs to be 100% height */
  flex-direction: row;  /* make the child divs into columns */
}
#body > div,
#body > div > div {
  /* these make the child divs and their children grow to fill the height of the columns in the body */
  display: flex;  
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="md-col-12" id="header">
    header
  </div>
  <div class="md-col-12" id="body">
    <!-- I have added this wrapping div for the body -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="sidebar-left-test">
        md-4
        <br>md-4
        <br>md-4
        <br>md-4
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="content">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the **scrollbars** always visible you can us this code:

```
/*Scroll bar nav*/
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px !important;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #dddddd;    
}
```

However, the **thumb** will always disappear if there is enough space for no scrolling required.

Comment: thanks for the answer but did not help :(, 

the images above show whe arrows disappear when the user resize the browser upwards, so I want to my green div be responsive and the arrows always be seeing  .

edit: the width is fine I am trying fix the height to be responsive when the user resize it from the bottom to up understand?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this would work. You can style the **thumb** also.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px !important;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #dddddd;    
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but did not help :(, 

the images above show whe arrows disappear when the user resize the browser upwards, so I want to my green div be responsive and the arrows always be seeing  .

edit: the width is fine I am trying fix the height to be responsive when the user resize it from the bottom to up understand?